# Is git rebase from current branch *exactly* the same as the explicit version from another branch?

Tags: git, rebase, explicit

I spose this is a basic question but in most posts I don't see people use rebase with an explicitly defined branch (to rebase) much so I'm just wondering if there's a reason?

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

VS explicit:

```
git checkout random-possibly-orphand-branch
git rebase master feature
```

Is there any caveats to the latter? Does defining an explicit branch name care where HEAD is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just that rebase "feels" like an operation on HEAD. The docs say that if you specify a branch, rebase starts by doing a `git checkout` of that branch, so I believe the effect is absolutely identical.

Comment: OK I'll take your word for it :D
If you've just checked out an orphan branch it doesn't work (until you do  a commit there) but other than that it's always worked :)